# Command to Add semicolon to endf of line in C# in VSCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm used to Javascript and Swift where semicolon line endings are optional and now I'm working in C#. I'm pretty good at remembering to add them but it's a small (but large enough) annoyance to reach all over to the end or right-arrow key to add that semicolon.

I imagine that auto-adding semicolons would assume too much on the part of the coder, so I'd love to be able to assign a key command that adds a semicolon to the end of the current line and then adds a line (aka goes to the next line).

Is there such a command? ctrl+shift+p search (or keyboard shortcut search) for "ending", "end", or "semicolon" didn't give me anything useful. Thanks!

Comment: You can always write an extension that does this...

Comment: Probably not the only one, but the first one out of a google search: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros

Comment: Damn @OguzOzgul that looks great!

Comment: There must have been a reason why it pops up at the top :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrisvltn.vs-code-semicolon-insertion) that does exactly what you want:

- Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> adds a semicolon and a new line
- Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> adds a semicolon only.

---

Or, you can use the <kbd>end</kbd> key (or <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>) to go to the end of a line, then press <kbd>;</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. It's the same number of the keys as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>!

Comment: Same number of keystrokes but the end key forces me to move my hand instead of just my fingers. This looks like just the trick thanks!